# How to print all the data in table2 related with table 1

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have two tables users and subjects

users has this field username,id,email,etc.
subjects has this field  math,english, id, user_id,

/***UsersController.php***/

```
public function grade($id = null)
    {

       $users = $this->Users->get($id, [
        'contain' => [
            'Subjects'
        ]
      ]);
      $this->set('users', $users);
      $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
      //pr($users);exit;
    }
```

/***grade.ctp**/

```
[![<div class="users view large-10 medium-9 columns">
<?php   
//pr($users);exit;
foreach ($users as $user): ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-5 columns strings">
            <h6 class="subheader"><?= __('Username') ?></h6>
            <p><?= h($user->username) ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $this->user->username;?></p>

        </div>
        <div class="large-2 columns numbers end">
            <h6 class="subheader"><?= __('Id') ?></h6>
            <p><?= $this->Number->format($user->id) ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>][1]][1]
```

When I click the view grade data below will be output using pr($users)

[image: grade]

```
App\Model\Entity\User Object
(
    [username] => Tyra
    [password] => 97a8afcf419cc231e1bdcd8584b0a246
    [id] => 6
    [email] => tyra@gmail.com
    [profile_pic] => Resource id #196
    [destination] => 
    [created] => 
    [subjects] => Array
        (
            [0] => App\Model\Entity\Subject Object
                (
                    [math] => 100
                    [english] => 100
                    [history] => 100
                    [science] => 100
                    [id] => 11
                    [user_id] => 6
                    [[new]] => 
                    [[accessible]] => Array
                        (
                            [*] => 1
                        )

                    [[dirty]] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [[original]] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [[virtual]] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [[errors]] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [[repository]] => Subjects
                )

        )

    [[new]] => 
    [[accessible]] => Array
        (
            [*] => 1
        )

    [[dirty]] => Array
        (
        )

    [[original]] => Array
        (
        )

    [[virtual]] => Array
        (
        )

    [[errors]] => Array
        (
        )

    [[repository]] => Users
)
```

I try to pr($users); in grade.ctp view  I got the data above, which is correct containing the subjects fields. but how to print that in grade.ctp view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data are in object format,
you can simply do this:

```
<?php
    echo $users->username; // prints username
    echo $users->email;
?>
```

And to print subjects:

```
<?php 
  if(!empty($users->subjects)) {
      foreach($users->subjects as $subject) {
         echo $subject->math; // prints math
         echo $subject->english; // etc
      }
  }
?>
```

You can try [blog tutorials](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html) to be more familiar with these in a while..

Comment: Thank You so much @Manohar Khadka,till next time I have a long journey to learn this framework.